# Rsync realtime sync between Live environment and DR

Tags: centos, rsync

Actually I mounted two sharefolders on my Linux system. I use that to sync `/mnt/Live` and `/mnt/DR`. That is files on `/mnt/Live` and `/mnt/DR` should be the same.

To make that happen, i made one `rsync` script.

```
rsync -arhtuz -vv --delete --stats --progress /mnt/Live/ /mnt/DR
```

But the challenge here, as I have too many sub-directories and millions of files, it takes a minimum of 4 days to complete. So if one user add/modify a file, same will change after the script is finished. So it's a problem here.

Do you guys have a solution or you ever work on that before.

I'm new to Linux, a good idea will be highly appreciated.

Do you guys think that rsync command is good ? I have 4TB files to replicate, and it took 4-5 days for the job to finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [lsync daemon](https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/) uses rsync as a backend, but uses inotify to only sync files/directories that change (after an initial full pass). I'm not sure if it will scale to your size, but we've used that to replicate structures in the 1-2 TB region with very little problem.

Comment: Hi Ulrich, heard about that. Will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem when configured lsyncd.

Suppose I deleted a file by mistake in the remote directory, but it still exists in the source directory, I do not receive the deleted file back again in my remote directory.

Here's the sync command in the conf file.

```
    rsync     = {
    binary   = "/usr/bin/rsync",
    archive  = true,
    compress = true
                }
```